# Z-Score in SQL based on last 1 year

Tags: sql, statistics, analytics

I have daily data structured in the below format. Please note this is just a subset of the data and I had to make some modifications to be able to share it.

The first column is the [DataValue] for which I need to find the Z-score by IndexValue, [Qualifier], [QualifierCode] and [QualifierType]. I also have the [Date] column in there.

I essentially need to find the Z-score value for each data point by IndexValue, [Qualifier], [QualifierCode] and [QualifierType]. **The main point of focus here is that I have data for the last 3 years but in order to calculate Z-score, I only want to take the average and standard deviation for the last one year.**

Z-Score = [DataValue] - (Avg in last 1 year) / (Std Dev in last 1 year)

I am struggling with how to get average for the last one year. Would anybody be able to help me with this?

```
SELECT [IndexValue]
  ,[Qualifier]
  ,[QualifierCode]
  ,[QualifierType],[Date]
  ,[Month]
  ,[Year]
  ,[Z-Score] = ([DataValue] - ROUND(AVG([DataValue]),3))/ ROUND(STDEV([DataValue]),3)
  FROM [TABLEA] 
   GROUP BY [IndexValue]
  ,[Qualifier]
  ,[QualifierCode]
  ,[QualifierType]
  ,[Date]
  ,[Month]
  ,[Year]
  order by [IndexValue]
  ,[Qualifier]
  ,[QualifierCode]
  ,[QualifierType]
  ,[Date] desc
```

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqhJD.png

Answer (score 0):

You need window functions for this:

```
SELECT a.*,
       ( (DataValue - AVG(DataValue) OVER ()) /
         STDEV(DataValue) OVER ()
       ) as z_score
FROM [TABLEA] a;
```

Note: if `data_value` is an integer, you will need to convert it to a number with digits:

```
SELECT a.*,
       ( (DataValue - AVG(DataValue * 1.0) OVER ()) /
         STDEV(DataValue) OVER ()
       ) as z_score
FROM [TABLEA] a;
```

Rounding for the calculation seems to be way off base, unless your intention is to produce a z-like score that isn't really a z-score.

Comment: I did go down this route, but with this does it take the average for the data points in the last 1 year?

Comment: @KruthikaKumaraguru . . . No.  That is not part of your question (or at least not part of the code in your question -- I see a mention in the title but not explanation at all on that point).  You can add a `where` clause to limit the results to rows just in the past year.